# How to do OR masking operation in Image processing in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask

I have a code in C# which is giving me a masking result. But I couldn't do it in python. Can anyone help me on how to do it? Is it possible in python? I almost went through the python openCV documentation

```
public void OROPeration()
       {
           IplImage orImage = Cv.CreateImage(src.Size, BitDepth.U8, 3);
           Cv.Or(src, mask, orImage, null);
           Cv.SaveImage("4.jpg", orImage);
       }
```

Original image

[image]
Masking image
[image]
Result need to obtain
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a function in opencv, `bitwise_or`, I guess it'd do what you want.

```
import cv2 

fin_image = cv2.bitwise_or(src_image, masking_image)
```

Comment: Sir can i have a documentation of that. If so I'll be grateful.